# pdflatex: glyph undefined (symbols disappear from included pdf)

Tags: fonts, graphics, pdftex, symbols

I have a plot in pdf format which I include in my LaTeX document with `\includegraphics`. When I use `pdflatex` to compile I get

```
pdfTeX warning: /usr/bin/pdflatex (file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/stix/STIXGeneral-Italic.pfb): glyph `afii61289' undefined
```

and indeed one particular symbol from the plot is gone in the pdf. (The plot was created with TMathText in [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch), exported as eps and converted to pdf. The missing symbol is "\ell".)

Looking through the answers here, I found the `\pdfmapline` command. Not knowing exactly what is does I tried to include

```
\pdfmapline{KEAHSX+STIXGeneral-Italic}
```

at the beginning of my .tex file and indeed, compiling took a while and the missing symbol is now there. But. The font of the text body is now replaced by a pixel font, which obviously I don't want. (The fonts in included pdf plots are fine.)

So is there a better way to solve my original problem?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{missing_ell.pdf}
\end{document}
```

`missing_ell.pdf`: download [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=58129598848981965259&t=5812959884898196525992091)

The pdf has the `\ell` the output when running `pdflatex` doesn't.

### Create the plot

To recreate the plot (note: you can just download the file from the link above), do this in ROOT6:

```
a = new TH1F("h","h",1,-0.5,0.5)
a->GetXaxis()->SetBinLabel(1, "\\text{VR }W+\\,\\text{jets }(m_\\text{T2}(\\ell,\\tau))")
a->Draw()
```

Draw canvas as eps, convert to pdf with `epstopdf`.

Comment: Let me know in case I should add more information, e.g. the output from `pdffonts` etc. For the final pdf it's pretty long so I decided against including it for now, as I don't think it has additional information. `KEAHSX+STIXGeneral-Italic` is embedded in both the plot and the final pdf.

Comment: You should make a minimal example that we can use for tests. Naturally the pdf of the plot you are including is needed too.

Comment: I was afraid you'd ask for that as the plot is not public yet... I'll try to come up with a dummy plot.

Comment: I added an MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (it will make your pdf larger).

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{missing_ell.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, fixes the problem, and the size increase is O(1 %). I can live with that :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work in `beamer`?

Comment: My comment above below your question is still valid.

Comment: Putting `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` as first line (before the line with `\documentclass`) works in `beamer`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an EPS file with script ell created with ROOT6.22/02 https://www.dropbox.com/s/03n8y8xjtxkalvz/ell1.eps?dl=0.

I find the simplest approach is to use a bulk editor to replace STIX with STIXX in the eps files before conversion. This helps to remove the conflict between the version of STIXGeneral-Italic in ROOT (Version 0.9) and that included in TeXLive (version 1.1-beta1 for TeXLive 2017).